# Parsing a value of a variable onto another variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I parse the value of the `constant` named `currentTab` to that of the one named `tabToActivate`?

```
function panel(event) {
    const tab = event.currentTarget.closest(".tab");
    const container = tab.closest(".login-sign");
    const currentTab = event.currentTarget.dataset.forTab;
    const tabToActivate = container.querySelector(".tabcontent[data-tab ='${currentTab}']");
    
    console.log(tabToActivate)//outputs null perhaps due to improper parsing
}
```

Comment: I guess, it would make sense to share corresponding html to make sure your query is valid.

Comment: _"perhaps due to improper parsing"_ - You're not parsing anything in your excerpt.

Comment: `".tabcontent[data-tab ='${currentTab}']"` - a template literal uses backticks and not regular quotes

Comment: You have to use template literals if you want to interpolate the variable value as you are trying to do: ``const tabToActivate = container.querySelector(`.tabcontent[data-tab ='${currentTab}']`);``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though your question is not too clear but i think i got it. We can only pass a variable in a string by using back ticks not quotes;

```
const tabToActivate = container.querySelector(`.tabcontent[data-tab="${currentTab}"]`);
```

Comment: Please wrap the attribute value in quotes to get a valid selector: `="${currentTab}"`